# How can I prove this regarding Cyclotomic Cosets?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, galois-theory, finite-fields

For a positive integer $n$, let $[n]$ denotes the set $[n]:=\{1,2,3,...,n\}$.

Let $m$ be a positive integer, then define a set $A$ as

$$A:= [2^m - 2]\big\backslash [2^{m-1}-2]$$.

Now, define the Cyclotomic Coset of $2^{m-1}-1$ as
$$B:=\big\{\big((2^{m-1}-1)2^{j}\big) \bmod (2^{m}-1)\  :\ j\in\mathbb{Z}_+\big\}.$$
It is not difficult to see that
$$B:= \{2^{m-1}-1\} \cup \{2^m -1 - 2^{i-1}\ :\ 1\leq i \leq m-1\},$$
and hence $B \subset A$.

Now, define a set $C$ as

$$C:= A\backslash B.$$

Now, I am trying to prove the following:

$\textbf{Preposition:}$ For all $x\in C$, there exists a positive integer $j$ such that
$$(x. 2^j)\bmod(2^{m}-1)\in [2^{m-1} - 2].$$

$\textbf{Here is what I have tried}:$

Let $w = x - (2^{m-1}-1)$.Then it is not difficult to see that
$$1\leq w \leq 2^{m-1}-2,\ \mbox{such that $(2^{m-1}-1 + w)\notin B$}.$$
Now,
\begin{align} 
(x\cdot2^j)\bmod(2^m-1) &= \Big(\big((2^{m-1}-1)+ w \big)2^j\Big)\bmod(2^m-1)\\
 & = \Big(\big((2^{m-1}-1)+ w\big)\bmod(2^m-1)\cdot 2^{j}\bmod(2^m-1)\Big)\bmod(2^m-1)\\
 & = \Big(\big((2^{m-1}-1)+ w\big)\cdot 2^{j\bmod(m)}\Big)\bmod(2^m-1)\\
 & = \Big(\big((2^{m-1}-1)+ w\big)\cdot 2^r\Big)\bmod(2^m-1),\ \mbox{where $r = j\bmod(m)$}\ \ \ (1).
\end{align}
When $r = 0$, equation $(1)$ becomes
$$(x\cdot2^j)\bmod(2^m-1) = \Big(\big((2^{m-1}-1)+ w\big)\Big)\bmod(2^m-1) = (2^{m-1}-1)+ w = x \notin [2^{m-1}-2].$$
When $1\leq r \leq m-1$, equation $(1)$ becomes
\begin{align}
(x\cdot2^j)\bmod(2^m-1) & = \Big(\big((2^{m}-2)+ 2w\big)\cdot 2^{r-1}\Big)\bmod(2^m-1)\\
& = \Big(\big((2^{m}-1)+ (2w -1)\big)\cdot 2^{r-1}\Big)\bmod(2^m-1)\\
& = \Big(\big((2^{m}-1)\cdot2^{r-1}+ (2w -1)\cdot2^{r-1}\big)\Big)\bmod(2^m-1)\\
& = \big((2w -1)\cdot2^{r-1}\big)\bmod(2^m-1).\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (2)
\end{align}
Now, I have stuck on equation (2). Somehow, I have to prove that for some $1\leq r \leq m-1$, we have $\big((2w -1)\cdot2^{r-1}\big)\bmod(2^m-1)\in [2^{m-1}-2]$.

Anybody here have a better idea of proving my preposition?

Comment: Now, I am able to prove it.

Comment: Please take a look at our [MathJax Guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619). You want to use `\pmod` for congruences and `\bmod`for the the so called *binary mod* that simply calculates the remainder of an integer when divided by another. Math people prefer the former, and programmers the latter (an admittedly crude description), and there are subtle differences between them.

Comment: Also, observe that a period, `.`, is a punctuation character marking the end of a sentence, or a decimal point. If you want a multiplication sign, us `\cdot`. That will properly elevate the dot, and also the spacing around it then matches the expectations.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the smallest integers in cyclotomic cosets modulo $N=2^m-1$. If $\mathcal{C}$ is such a coset and $N-x$ is the smallest element in it, then you cannot have $2x<N$ for otherwise $2(N-x)\equiv N-2x\in\mathcal{C}$ would be smaller (congruence obviously modulo $N$).

So either $x=2^{m-1}$, when you have the coset $B$ you already identified. Or, when $x>2^{m-1}$, the coset has at least one element $<2^{m-1}-1$. That is exactly what you wanted to prove.